# Plugin permissions for Editor role

Tags: plugins, admin, users, user-roles, editor

I've added a plugin called Orbisius Simple Notice but I notice this applied to several plugins I have installed. The plugin works fine when logged in as an Admin. However, my clients who manage the site use accounts set to Editor roles. When any of the Editor accounts try to access the options page for the plugin, they get the following message:

"You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page."

I use User Role Editor to ensure they have permissions to edit plugins. However, I know the issue is not related to this as I enabled all permissions as a test and I still got the above error. So I figure it's hardcoded into the plugin. Source for the plugin: http://pastebin.com/UhrvkiXv

The only bit I saw that seemed appropriate was:

```
function orbisius_simple_notice_setup_admin() {
add_options_page('Orbisius Simple Notice', 'Orbisius Simple Notice', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'orbisius_simple_notice_options_page');
```

But the users have manage_options enabled. I tried changing to edit_pages etc. but still no luck.

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 1):

manage_options is an admin role so I'd still try and changing it even if you've changed the roles elsewhere.
See http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Editor for more info.

Try the following:

```
add_options_page('Orbisius Simple Notice', 'Orbisius Simple Notice', 'edit_others_posts', __FILE__, 'orbisius_simple_notice_options_page');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I gave that a go but no joy. I double checked and they definitely got edit_others_posts enabled.

Comment: Couple of Questions. Are you able to disable User Role Editor while testing? Are you sure that the 'Editors' are Editors as far as Wordpress is concerned, or have you just added editing rights using User Role Editor? Also, try changing edit_others_posts to update_plugins

Comment: Another option, try adding this to functions.php although you need to be comletely aware of the privileges you are granting to your editors: `get_role('editor')->add_cap('edit_theme_options');`

Comment: Again, thanks for the reply, no joy again though. Tried disabling User Role Editor and adding in the various combinations you mentioned. User Role Editor is definitely just tweaking the pre-defined Editor role. I'm not too worried about what I give access to for the Editor roles as I've removed all of menu items they don't need manually and very few people have access so I doubt anyone would try pasting in other admin pages they shouldn't go to.

Comment: I can only suggest changing edit_theme_options and trying  it with different values such as, manage_options, activate_plugins, update_plugins, etc.

Comment: Whilst that didn't fix the problem, I did notice something potentially helpful. If the capability needed is change to something the user role can't access, the link in the admin sidebar does disappear and when I have it as something they do have rights to, it appears in the sidebar. This leads me to believe that line of the plugin in not ultimately responsible for the issue as even when it's available in the admin menu, the permission error is still given.

Comment: Hmm. While reading into this yesterday, I read a few people saying that the capabilities can be managed by the plugin, so maybe you're right. I just can't see it anywhere though. :(

Comment: Have you recently moved servers or changed the URL, etc? If so, read this URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815461/you-do-not-have-sufficient-permissions-to-access-this-page-without-any-change

Comment: I don't know if this can help, but to fine tune roles capabilities and personalize backend displayed items and functionalities for each role, i use in combination 2 very stable and active plugins: **User Role Editor** and **Adminimize**. Possibilities are infinite and you can even create specific user roles as needed.